# C# Indexer Property with different types

Tags: c#

Is there any way to use indexed properties with different types.
I tried to search this forum, but this question is a little bit different as I simply cannot specify a name to indexed properties.

So how it is possible to do so (for sure compiler complains):
One property returns an object another array. In visual basic this type is possible and in C# not?

Property1:

```
private Point3d this[int index] {
    get {
        return this.m_Levels[this.m_NodeLevel[index]][index];
    }
    set {
        this.m_Levels[this.m_NodeLevel[index]][index] = value;
    }
}
```

Proeperty 2:

```
private Point3d[] this[int index] {
    get
    {
        return this.m_Levels[index];
    }
    set
    {
        this.m_Levels[index] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, not sure what you're asking for here. You have two code samples - are they both your attempts to do what you want? You say this works in VB - can you point us to that example? Finally, might be clearer if you also show what the calling code would look like (there again, it might not)

Comment: What is the complain from the compiler?

Comment: You can't use two `this[int index] ` in one class, Why did you want to do that?

Comment: Also, of course, if you have something working in VB, there are plenty of VB <-> C# converters that you can try out and see what they produce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As @slfan said, you can't give two identic signature for your `this` property.**

---

For your understanding, you can convert this

```
public int this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        return this.m_array[index];
    }
    set
    {
        this.m_array[index] = value;
    }
}
```

with this *translation*:

```
public int get_Item(int index)
{
    return this.m_array[index];
}

public void set_Item(int index, int value)
{
    this.m_array[index] = value;
}
```

---

To make it smaller:

```
int this[int index] { get { ... } }
```

is equivalent (*equal?*) to

```
int get_Item(int index) { ... }
```

---

In the same way that you **can** make this:

```
int get_Item(int index) { ... }
int get_Item(byte index) { ... }
int get_Item(float index) { ... }
int get_Item(string index) { ... }
```

you **can** also make this:

```
int this[int index] { get { ... } }
int this[byte index] { get { ... } }
int this[float index] { get { ... } }
int this[string index] { get { ... } }
```

---

**BUT** in the same way that you **cannot** make this:

```
public int get_Item(int index) { ... }
public int get_Item(int index) { ... } // <-- error
```

nor:

```
public int get_Item(int index) { ... }
public float get_Item(int index) { ... } // <-- error
```

you **cannot** make this:

```
int this[int index] { get { ... } }
int this[int index] { get { ... } } // <-- error
```

nor:

```
int this[int index] { get { ... } }
float this[int index] { get { ... } } // <-- error
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the same signature this is not possible. How should the compiler know which indexer method you call? You might want to use a 2nd parameter (e.g. index for node level), then the compiler could distinct the two calls. For property 1 you could use this code.

```
private Point3d this[int nodeLevel, int index] {
    get {
        return this.m_Levels[this.m_NodeLevel[nodeLevel]][index];
    }
    set {
        this.m_Levels[this.m_NodeLevel[nodeLevel]][index] = value;
    }
}
```

Instead of an indexer you can always use a function with a name (e.g. `int GetValueAtLevel(int index)`).